# What is the difference between "twice as much" and "twice as much as"?

Tags: comparative-constructions

I saw two examples describing this kind of usage

1. Americans are sending more than twice as much trash to landfills than the government estimates
2. My worth is twice as much as he has. (This is my own example, I cannot find the OP, so I just made another one similar to OP's)

Answer (score 3):

- “twice as much” a change to a single thing, e.g. trash
- “twice as much as” a comparison to something else. e.g. my worth to his worth

In the second sentence I would have written something like, "My worth is twice as much as his."

Answer (score 3):

Your first example is ungrammatical, although in a very minor way which will pass entirely unnoticed in speech or casual writing. The author uses the wrong preposition to complete the comparative construction.

> Americans are sending more than twice as much trash to landfills **<s>than</s> *as*** the government estimates.

*Than* is proper with *more*, and I suspect the author confused himself by using more and then losing track of his sentence:

> Americans are sending more trash to landfills **<sup>ok</sup>than** the government estimates.

But  *twice as much* **can** be used by itself with entire propriety.

> The government estimates that Americans send X million tons of trash to landfills every year. In fact, they send **twice as much**.

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* calls this a *fused-head determiner*: the quantifier/determiner *twice as much* is permitted to  “fuse” with its head nominal if the nominal can be identified from the context. You see the same thing with many sorts of determiner:

> Those neckties are red.  <s>These neckties</s> **These** are blue.
>   Some frogs are green. <s>Other frogs</s> **Others** are brown.